Bootstrapping of binary variables using Lavaan
I am a new user of R and I encounter problem in bootstrapping with my model.
All exogenous and endogenous and mediator variables are binary outcomes. I tried according to the solution by adding se = "bootstrap", estimator = "DWLS", verbose = TRUE but it still does not work.
Kindly request your suggestions and advice on it. Thank you for your time.
Here is my code
model19 <-'ls ~ a1*participation1 + health_status
        health_status ~ a2*participation1
        hsu~ d1*ls + d2*health_status +c1*participation1 +e1*rural + e2*female +
        e3*middle+e4*oldest+e5*primary+e6*secondary+e7*higher+e8*married+
        e9*all+e10*employ+e11*support+e12*pension
        indirect1:=a1*d1
        indirect2:=a2*d2
        overallindirect:= indirect1+ indirect2
        total:=overallindirect +c1+e1+e2+e3+e4+e5+e6+e7+e8+e9+e10+e11+e12'
fit19 <- sem(model19, data = old_main, ordered = c("hsu", "ls", "health_status"),
             se = "bootstrap", estimator = "DWLS", verbose = TRUE)
summary(fit19, standardized=TRUE, ci=TRUE, fit.measures=TRUE)


What error do you get? Is this primarily a programming question or a statistics question?

The error is that the model was not converged.

It appeared like that and  output is not get.lavoptim    ... done.
OK -- niter =   55  fx =  0.004210046
... bootstrap draw number:   23Estimating sample thresholds and correlations ... done
Number of observations                         19136
lavpartable bounds ... done.
lavstart           ... done.
lavmodel           ... done.
lavoptim           ... start:
attempt 1 -- default options
objective function  = 0.0044598398194682
quasi-Newton steps using NLMINB:
objective function  = 0.0044598398194682
objective function  = 0.0044318479642188
